Find the limit $\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x) e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x) - f(0)}$
I'm currently working on a set of problems on differentiability, and I'm stuck at the problem I have right here.
Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and that $f'(0) \neq 0$. Find the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) e^x - f(0)}{f(x) \cos(x) - f(0)}.
$$
Note, I'm not "allowed" to use L'Hôpital's rule in order to solve this problem. Everything I've tried does not really give me anything, however since it is custom here I will write down what I've done:
In the numerator I add $f(0)e^x - f(0)e^x$, and in the denominator I add $ f(0)\cos(x) - f(0)\cos(x)$ and get
$$
\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{e^x (f(x) - f(0)) + f(0)(e^x - 1)}{\cos(x) (f(x) - f(0)) + f(0) (\cos(x) - 1)}
$$
Which looks nice, but I do not know what I get out of it.

Hint: Write $f(x)=f(0)+xg(x)$  where $g(x)=\frac {f(x)-f(0)} x$.

Consider the functions:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
g(x) &= f(x)e^x \\
h(x) &= f(x)\cos{x}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and rewrite the limit as:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{h(x)-h(0)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}}{\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}} = \\
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\text{using the definition of a derivative and the fact that } \\
g(x) \text{ and } h(x) \text{ are differentiable at } x=0
\end{array}
\right] \\
= \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}} = \frac{g'(x)|_{x=0}}{h'(x)|_{x=0}} = 1+ \dfrac{f(0)}{f'(0)}
$$

Good thinking but we are given that $f(x)$ is differentiable at zero, not everywhere.

@Vasili, you're absolutely right, thank you for pointing that out. I'll fix it.

Let $g(x) = f(x)e^x, h(x) = f(x)\cos(x)$. Then, $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $0$. We have,
$$
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x)e^x - f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x) - f(0)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{f(x)e^x - f(0)}{x - 0}}{\dfrac{f(x)\cos(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x - 0}}{\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x - 0}} = \dfrac{g'(0)}{h'(0)} = \dfrac{f'(0) + f(0)}{f'(0)}
$$

+1. Consider writing just $x$ instead of $x-0$

As an alternative, by differentiability at $x=0$ we have

$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0) x+o(x)$
$e^x=1+x+o(x)$
$\cos x=1+o(x)$

then
$$\frac{f(x) e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos x - f(0)}=\frac{f'(0)x+f(0)x+o(x)}{xf'(0)+o(x)}=\frac{f'(0)+f(0)+o(1)}{f'(0)+o(1)}\to 1+\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$$
